# K-nearest neighbour imputation of missing values

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, missing-data, k-nearest-neighbour, data-imputation

I have a dataset where the columns correspond to features and the rows correspond to data points. I have around 5'000 data points and 8 features. Now, I would like to impute the missing values with the nearest neighbour method. For this I'm using the Matlab function `knnimpute`.

Let's say feature 4 of row 10 has a missing value. Should I search the nearest data points (rows) or the nearest columns? I tend to search the nearest data points because I want the the feature value of a closest data point. I think in this case I have to call `knnimpute(data')`, i.e. transposed.

Of course there is the possibility that a whole row has only missing values (or more than 50% missing values). I think Matlab does no imputation if a whole row has only missing values.

Is there a rule what to do if a whole row has only missing values? And what should I do if there are e.g. more than 50% missing values in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Should I search the nearest data points (rows) or the nearest columns?*
   Yes indeed. You should search for the nearest point (i.e. row) and impute the missing value in feature *j* using the *j*th feature from the nearest neighbours. I don't know why in `knnimpute()` Matlab works by columns, in that case is indeed correct to transpose the dataset.
2. *Is there a rule what to do if a whole row has only missing values? And what should I do if there are e.g. more than 50% missing values in a row?*
   Well if a whole row (or better, column) has only missing value the `knnimpute()` will must certainly fail. You can fill such column with a given value, let's say 0, so it doesn't affect the dissimilarity measure. If a given row (column) has instead a lot of missing values and you don't want (or you can't) use `knnimpute()` you can implement your very own imputation technique. A standard technique is the mean of the column itself (counting only non-missing values, of course and you can easily do it in Matlab thanks to the `nanmean()` function). On StackOverflow I posted an answer, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680426/missing-value-in-data-analysis/35684975#35684975), regarding several missing data imputation techniques. Maybe you can read this and choose for a nice technique in such drastic scenario.

Comment: Nice answer :) Strange that knnimpute() in Matlab works by columns. The other way round like you mostly see it in R makes more sense to me...  According to filling rows with only missing values with a own method (e.g. mean or something else) I have to add that it is important to first do the knn imputation. (excluding this rows) And afterwards fill these with the mean. Otherwise your custom procedure has a negative impact on the knn imputation.